# Hodge structure of abelian surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, derived-categories, hodge-theory, algebraic-surfaces

In my case, I have an abelian surface $A$ of (2,8)-polarization, and I have some finite group (may not be abelian group) $G$ acting on $A$ without fixed point. I want to understand when there is a Hodge isometry $$\phi: H^{2*}(A/G,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{2*}(A,\mathbb{Z}),$$ where $\phi$ is the map induced from the natrual morphism $A \to A/G$.

For any abelian surface $X$, the dimension of $H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is ${4 \choose k}$, hence it is enough to show $\phi$ is injective.

The background for this question is: according to Orlov, Mukai that $D(A),D(A/G)$ are derived equivalent iff there exists such Hodge isometry. I don't know if the polarization type is relevent or not, but that is what I have in my case.

Any comments/suggestions/references are very welcome!!!

Comment: What you ask is not clear at all. Is $\phi=p^*$, where $p:A\rightarrow A/G$ is the quotient map? Is $G$ abelian? What is the role of the polarization in your question?

Comment: (1)$\phi = p^*$ (2) $G$ may not be abelian (3) I don't know what is the role of the polarization in my problem, but that's the (only) information I know about the abelian surface.

Comment: $p^*$ is *not* an isometry unless $G$ is trivial. I suggest that you begin by a good book on the subject, for instance Barth et al.

Comment: This is certainly not true - abelian variety and its dual are derived equivalent and hence when $G=K(L)$ we should have the isometry by Orlov & Mukai...

Comment: It is true -- it is just an elementary fact about cohomology of surfaces. There might be an isometry, but it is certainly not $p^*$.